# The object is not able to accept a variable from outside it

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code. I am trying to save into database, the value of user's IP and a conversation that I get from a form. However, I am not able to as the conversation is from req.body.conversation which I am unable to get access inside the object. I tried using a normal string and it works perfectly fine. Just, I am unable to get hold of req.body.conversation as well as the ip from inside the object. Please help.

```
    app.route("/conversation").post(function(req,res){
     var ip=getClientIp(req);
     const newConversation=new Conversation({
        userIP:ip,
        conversation:req.body.conversation
     });
     newConversation.save(function(err){
       if(!err){
          res.redirect("/forum");
       }
     });
    
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. We don't know what's in `req` or why accessing it might be failing.

Comment: Have you given `console.log(req.body.conversation)` to see what is returned?

Comment: const {conversation} = req.body;
const newConversation = new Conversation({userIP:ip,conversation});

Have you tried using destructuring ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much guys. I got the solution. req.body was returning an array, so I added index to req.body.conversation[0] and it works.